# Script doesn't always fully execute when ajaxed in with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this clause to execute a script under certain condition;

```
//if artist page clicked run profile script
if (id == 'artist_link') {
        $.getScript("AJAX/get_profile.js");
}
```

The problem i'm having is that the script will often not fully execute. Sometimes nothing will be executed other times only parts of it will execute. I can't really provide any more details than this. Strange occurence though is that it always executes fully when firebug is open and I can't find any problems. The browsers that i've tested on and both have this problem are chrome and firefox

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNt4s/) with `get_profile.js` file in.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the 3 lines you posted, unsurprisingly. There may be something wrong in the file you're getting (get_profile.js), but we may never know - we're not mind readers

Comment: Have you tried Firefox's built-in web console (as opposed to Firebug)?

Comment: How do you know I doesn't fully execute, do you get any message in the error console (not Firebug's one)?

Comment: I get no error message in the console but i know it doesn't fully excecute since the functions in the file are not carried out. @Joe Please take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TNt4s/)

Comment: @nbs189: Is that script in the fiddle your `get_profile.js`? You've got a superfluous block (braces) around your ajax call, but it looks syntactically  good otherwise. Add a logging statement in the end to see whether it is executing correctly, there may also be issues with the event handlers (e.g. when the script executes after `window.onload`)

Comment: @Bergi please look at my answer. I found the solution, don't know why I didn't see it before.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but as far as I'm aware, `$(location)` isn't valid jQuery. Replacing `$(location).attr('pathname')` with just `window.location.pathname` would remove a likely error.

A couple of other general things, which shouldn't really affect whether or not it works, but are worth mentioning to improve overall niceness:

- `data` returned from a JSON call is an object, not an array. To access the `DP` element of it for a display picture, you should use `data.DP` not `data['DP']` (same for `name`, and several other elements
- `.click()` is deprecated, use `.on()` to bind events instead
- You're looping over an collection ( `$.each (data, function(key, val){` ) and inside the loop, are modifying the DOM ( `$.append()` ) - you'd be better off instead building up a string of HTML during the loop, then add it in a single append after the loop, as DOM insertions are slow for performance
- You're using the same selector multiple times (see `$('#origin')`), which causes jQuery to have to look the element up every time. Either cache it and then call methods on that:

  - `$origin = $('#origin');`
- or chain calls to the same element:

  - `$('#origin').html('a').append('b').append('c');`

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost 100% certain there is a bug somewhere in your get_profile.js file.  If it's executing at all, then there isn't any problem with the loading of the file.  The problem resides somewhere in your js file and we can't really debug that without seeing the code from it.

Comment: Okay I shall post the get_profile.js. The reason I think there is not a bug is because it works perfectly sometimes and always works perfectly when the page is actually loaded the normal way and not ajaxed in.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed It! I don't know why I wasn't seeing this but the script was being ajaxed in before the page had been ajaxed in resulting in the script becoming unfunctional. Anyway with a bit of fidlling i've fixed it. Thanks for the help!